# Swift Xcode getting <<error type>> from generic type parameter inside closure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, types

Swift's way to create a red button:

```
let button: UIButton = {
      let button = UIButton()
      button.backgroundColor = .red
      return button
}()
```

With my extension (kotlin's approach):

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton().apply(){ this in
    this.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

There are two problems with my extension, first one is that Xcode doesn't recognize the closure parameter "this", it shows << error type >>, so I don't have autocomplete (although it's working), and the second one is that I would like to be able to infer the generic type since I'm already instantiating it.

The extension:

```
extension NSObject {
    func apply<T>(_ closure: (T) -> ()) -> T {
        let this = self as! T
        closure(this)
        return this
    }
}
```

I hope someone can find a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that Swift cannot infer the type of `T`. You did not and cannot tell Swift to use the current type as the type of the closure. `Self` is only available in the result type of methods in a class.

You can do something like this:

```
func apply<T>(_ obj: T, closure: (T) -> Void) -> T {
    closure(obj)
    return obj
}
apply(UIButton()) { this in this.backgroundColor = .red }
```

but I don't think that's what you want. You want the word `apply` to be in the middle, right?

Unfortunately, I cannot think of how you would achieve that. As an alternative, you can try replacing the word "apply" with an operator. For example, I think `-->` is quite suitable for this.

```
infix operator -->

func --> <T>(obj: T, closure: (T) -> Void) -> T {
    closure(obj)
    return obj
}
let button = UIButton() --> { this in this.backgroundColor = .red }
```

Comment: Your second approach just blew up my mind, I'm so used to java, only a week developing in iOS/Swift, I didn't even know that you could use operators like that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you. If the extension is inside a class put it outside of the class so it's on its own. If that is how it is already try clearing the errors with the command (command + k), this will reload them. If the error remains it's very confusing because it is working fine for me.